# Сложение больших чисел

Tags: алгоритм, delphi, freepascal

Потребовалось работать с числами в более 2000 знаков. Решил записывать их в string.
Написал функцию сложения(знаю, говнокод):

```
function Add(i1, i2 :TStringWord):TStringWord;
var 
 tswResult :TStringWord;
 bFirstLarger, bNew:boolean;
 i:Word;
 iBuf:byte;
begin
 bNew:=false;
 bFirstLarger:=false;
 if Length(i1)>=Length(i2) then bFirstLarger:=true;
 if bFirstLarger=true then
  begin
   SetLength(tswResult, Length(i1));
   for i:=Length(i1) downto 0 do
    begin
     if i<=Length(i2) then
     begin
      iBuf:=StrToInt(i1[i])+StrToInt(i2[i]);
      if bNew=true then iBuf:=iBuf+1;
      if iBuf>9 then
       begin
        bNew:=true;
        iBuf:=iBuf-10;
       end;
      tswResult[i]:=IntToChar(iBuf);
     end
     else tswResult[i]:=i1[i];
    end;
  end
  else
   SetLength(tswResult, Length(i2));
   for i:=Length(i2) downto 0 do
    begin
     if i<=Length(i1) then
     begin
      iBuf:=StrToInt(i1[i])+StrToInt(i2[i]);
      if bNew=true then iBuf:=iBuf+1;
      if iBuf>9 then
       begin
        bNew:=true;
        iBuf:=iBuf-10;
       end;
      tswResult[i]:=IntToChar(iBuf);
     end
     else tswResult[i]:=i2[i];
    end;  
 Add:=tswResult;
end;
```

Но при попытке работать с ней получаю

```
An unhandled exception occurred at $000000000040482A :
EConvertError : "" is an invalid integer
  $000000000040482A
  $000000000040024C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас тут вообще неправильный алгоритм.

1. Вы выравниваете строки по старшим цифрам, а надо по младшим (правым, у которых индекс равен длине строки).
2. Когда цифры короткой строки закончились, Вы про перенос забываете.
3. Опять же с переносом. Длина результата может стать на 1 больше, чем длина максимальной строки.

Исправьте, а потом отлаживайте.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь похоже в одном из вызовов StrToInt конверсии в качестве Str аргумента внутрь попадает ""(пустая строка), что приводит к ошибке. Попробуйте индекс там заменить c i на i-1. Код малопонятный, поэтому не гарантирую что это сработает. Первая ссылка Google на запрос: [Работа с большими числами Delphi](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/big_numbers.html)